# Testing invertible matrices for closure under addition

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Determine whether the following subsets of V are subspaces of V. Justify your answers: if the subset is a subspace, verify the necessary properties a subspace must have; if it is not a subspace, show at least one required property which fails.

$W=$ set of invertible $2\times2$ matrices in $V=M_{22}$

I did the following test using a specific example:

$A=$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 1
 \\ \end{bmatrix} +$ $B=$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 1
 \\ \end{bmatrix} $ $=$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0  \\ 0 & 2
 \\ \end{bmatrix}$

This is a vector space in the set, but how do I know *all* invertible matrices fall into this category?

Comment: Is $A - A \in W$?

Comment: @T.Bongers I would say yes because it is the zero matrix??

Comment: Is ther zero matrix invertible?

Comment: @T.Bongers No... I don't believe so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$W$ is not closed under vector addition (and any subspace of a vector space must be closed under vector addition). Hence $W$ cannot be a subspace of $V$.

How do we know $W$ is not closed under addition? To show this we provide a counter-example:

- Let  $A\in W$. Then $-A \in W$. (I.e., if $A$ is invertible, $-A$ is
  invertible).
- But $A + (-A) = {\bf {0}} \notin W$,  since $\bf 0$ (the zero vector) is
  **not invertible** (and $W$ is defined to be the set of all *invertible* $2\times 2$ matrices).
- Hence our conclusion that $W$ is not closed under vector addition.

---

One can also simply argue that $W$ fails to contain the zero matrix, by definition of $W$. And since every vector subspace (space) must contain the zero vector, $W$ fails to be a subspace of $V$.

Comment: I understand your logic, but I guess I'm confused because I thought a vector space had to include the $0$ vector?  So how can I potentially have a vector space that does not include the zero vector?  I guess that's the point of this question haha?

Comment: That is indeed the point.

Comment: Indeed! The question is *whether* $W$ is a subspace. And it cannot be since it is not closed under vector addition, and it cannot be since it fails to contain the zero vector. Either reason, alone, gives us the desired conclusion.